# TbModal with CHtml::link not firing

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, yii

I'm working with a series of TbModal and CHtml Links to trigger their display, but the modals never show up.  The code looks correct and the generated HTML seems right, but no modal is displayed.

This is the code for the modal, which is looped, and each loop generates a new modal/link pair:

```
<?php $this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbModal', array('id'=>$list['wbse']));?>
  <div class="modal-header">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</a>
    <h3><?php echo Yii::t('cmin', 'project_details')?></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p><?php echo CHtml::encode($list['summary'])?></p>
    <p><?php echo CHtml::encode($list['objective'])?></p>
  </div>
<?php $this->endWidget();?>
```

And here's the CHtml::Link

```
<?php echo CHtml::link($list['wbse'], '#'.$list['wbse'], array(
    'data-toggle'=>'modal',
    'data-target'=>'#'.$list['wbse']
)); ?>
```

The generated HTML looks fine:

```
<a href="#P-000978.001" data-target="#P-000978.001" data-toggle="modal">P-000978.001</a>
```

But there's never a modal popped up.

Comment: Just realized the issue is with the content of the ID I'm using in the <div>.  It has a . in it that I'm not escaping, so jQuery can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be defining the id of the modal window in the wrong place. It needs to be part of the htmlOptions. So instead of this;

```
<?php $this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbModal', array('id'=>$list['wbse']));?>
```

try this

```
<?php $this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbModal', array('htmlOptions' => array('id'=>$list['wbse'])));?>
```

Comment: It's the same difference, as the 2nd parameter is assumed to be the htmlOptions (at least how I understood the docs).  Both pieces of code generate a modal that starts with `<div id="P-000978.001" class="modal hide fade">` thanks though.